# What is the difference between using self._variable and just self.variable in the constructor in Python

Tags: python, class, instance-variables

for Example if I create a class Point.

class Point:

```
def__init__(self, x, y):
    self._x = x
    self._y = y
```

and

class Point:

```
def__init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
```

what is the difference in the use of self._x and just self.x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single underscore is just a naming convention to state that the property should be considered "semi-private" (similarly double underscore means "private"), but it doesn't have a semantic difference: both versions of the code should behave exactly the same. According to [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> `_single_leading_underscore` : weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.
>
> `single_trailing_underscore_` : used by convention to avoid conflicts with a Python keyword.
>
> `__double_leading_underscore` : when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class `FooBar`, `__boo` becomes _`FooBar__boo`).
>
> `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__` : "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__` , `__import__` or `__file__` . Never invent such names; only use them as documented.

If, for some reason, you have a variable prefixed by an underscore and it is acceptable to publicly access this variable, then it is a good practice to include the name of this variable in your module's [__all__ list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python). This serves as a form of in-code documentation.

Comment: double underscore seems to mean **bold** in quotes :)